# TableView always nil

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode5.1

I have a weird problem with my TableView which is always set to nil. I'll explain more:

This is my storyboard:

[image: StoryBoard]

In my BuddyListViewController.m file I instantiate my ChatViewController :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
userName = (NSString *) [onlineBuddies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
JCChatViewController *chatController = [[JCChatViewController alloc] initWithUser:userName];
    [self presentViewController:chatController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

ChatViewController (.h) File

```
@interface JCChatViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    UITextField *messageField;
    UITableView *tView;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *messageField;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tView;

-(id) initWithUser:(NSString *) userName;
-(IBAction)sendMessage;
@end
```

I also linked my tableView with my tView property

ChatViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tView.delegate = self;
    self.tView.dataSource = self;
   [self.tView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
}
```

While debugging, I always have self.tView equal to nil, with is very bizarre, thus, my TableView Delegate methods are not invoked.

Best regards

Comment: Have you linked the outlet from file owner in xib??

Comment: Just to precise, when I set ChatViewController scene as an initial storyboard scene, I have no problem ! I do not know whats going on !!!

Comment: Try connecting your `dataSource` and `delegate` Outlets to The ViewController. Might just work out.

Comment: Remove the `messageField` and `tView` instance variables; you don't need them.

Comment: Also use of `retain` and `strong` in the same source file looks dodgy.

Comment: @iCoder : Thank you, but I have already tried this, but same result

Comment: You might want to set your delegate in -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated instead. See if that works.

Comment: Remove those instance variables. Just use the property variables.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments:
1- I removed instance variables 
2- I set my delegate in viewDidAppear: method
3- I replaced the retain by strong
But it's still not working

Comment: @Ali, all IBOutlet-s should be weak references. Not strong and not retain as in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create **JCChatViewController** object in code, you don't create it's view. If you want it's view to be created like it was described in your storyboard you have two options:

- Create it inside **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** using UIStoryboard's method

```
- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

You could take storyboard from your current view controller object.
Also you need to specify some **storyboard id** to **JCChatViewController** in your storyboard.

- Create a segue in storyboard, that would connect cells from your **Friends List** and **Chat** controller. You could pass any additional data to **Chat** controller inside method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

that should be overridden in **Friends List** controller.

Comment: Thanks Artem, but I already tried that and same result, not working and tView = nil

Comment: @Ali, which approach did you try?

Comment: I tried the Segue approach, yesterday, and that did not work, and, I was trying the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier, and every time my tView is nil ?!

Comment: @Ali, the code that you've posted here definitely doesn't connect view from storyboard to Chat view controller. So you should try to find out the reason why mentioned options didn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you I re-wrote my prepareForSegue Method, and the results are much better, I can see my TableView on the screen, without Data but that's not a problem. Thanks again and have a nice Day/evening/night